# Wrapper Facade Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm working on an issue of design patterns - I have used facade and adapter pattern in some systems in the past.

Now I've found [the wrapper facade pattern](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/wrapper-facade.pdf). If I understand it correct (I only have a vague idea) the wrapper facade is a combination of facade and adapter pattern.

Now I have some questions:

- When do I typically use the wrapper facade pattern?
- Does anyone know a book which discribes the wrapper facade pattern (ideally with an example in java)?
- Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key summarizing sentence in that paper is this:

> Facades hide complex class relationships behind a simpler API, whereas Wrapper Facades hide complex function and data structure relationships behind a richer class API.

Interpretation: Wrapper Facade pertains to an OOP layer above native, non-OOP API and code. This pattern is not very relevant to general Java development; examples of it are classes with a lot of `native` methods, like `java.io` stream implementations or the Abstract Windowing Toolkit (AWT).

Comment: Thanks - I hadnt taken that sentence in I guess.  Good to know

Answer (score 0):

From the link you've given I'm not sure I can tell the difference between a `Facade`and a `Wrapper Facade` - they appear to do exactly the same thing:  provide a simplified interface to a disparate set of low level functions/functionality.

As such I'm not sure that this "wrapper facade" does utilize the adaptor pattern - why would it need to?  If the only purpose of the facade is to provide a simplified API for a client then it has no need to *adapt* one thing to another.

Likewise if a client required a specific interface then a `Adaptor` would be the way to go, and there would be no need for a `Facade`

Again, this all assumes that I've read that link correctly :-)